# Im using Xcode and i want to make a button appear at random

Tags: xcode, macos, button, uibutton

I am having difficulties while using xcode to make a button appear at a random part of the screen everytime I tap it.

```
button.center = CGPointMake(button.frame.size.width / 2.0 + arc4random_uniform(150 -           
    button.frame.size.width), button.frame.size.height / 2.0 + arc4random_uniform(150 - 
    button.frame.size.height));
```

I keep getting the issues:

```
Identifier not found or '('
```

And I would like to know how to find the frame and the size
And if the “button” should be replaced by “UIButton”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IBAction method write this (just example)

```
button.frame=CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x+20,button.frame.origin.y+20,button.frame.size.width,button.frame.size,height);
```

Comment: doesnt move the subject that i want to move

Comment: how would i make a property of the button

Comment: @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton * myButton;

Comment: then go to xib or storyboard, select your button , press control and drag from your button to File's owner (a transparent cube like button ). it will automatically popup property name that you just make. connect to it . To make sure you built a successful connection, go to the class where you declare the property . there should be a dark grey circle on the left side.